# Use a jQuery script with a HTML button

Tags: jquery, django, forms

In my Django admin form, I have a field which looks like this:

[image: Model form rendered showing 5 fields including "Select All"]

The `Select All` button uses a `jQuery` script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_season_0').click(function (event) { //on click 
        if (this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        } else {
            $('.checkbox').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But the problem is : `Select All` is also a field in my `models` and I don't want to have it anymore. So I'm actually trying to apply a little modification. I would like to use a `HTML button` instead of `BooleanField` for `SelectAll`.

So I'm using this code in `change_form.html` :

```
<button id="selectall" type="button" class="checkbox"> Select All </ button>
```

I tried to change the id to `selectall` but that doesn't work. Help please ?

Comment: Only `<input type=checkbox>` or `<input type=radio>` can have the attribute `checked`. It's not valid for a `<button>` element. You can use css to style a checkbox to look like a button, if you want.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, you learned me something! Yes I'm going to use css I think its a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I've made a few assumptions here as you haven't included the full html.

You could leave the checkbox in place and just do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_season_0').click(function (event) { //on click 
        if (this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox').not('#id_season_0').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        } else {
            $('.checkbox').not('#id_season_0').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Adding the .not('#id_season_0') will mean the select all checkbox is ignored.

[jQuery .not() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

If you really want to go with the button then use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectAll').click(function (event) { //on click 
        if (this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        } else {
            $('.checkbox').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });
        }
    });

});
```

and html:

```
<button type="button" class="checkbox selectAll">Select All</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you I'll combine your first answer with css custom and it's ok :)

Comment: This will not work with a button element. `if (this.checked) { // check select status`. A button doesn't have a `checked` attribute.

Comment: I don't think he isn't trying to set the button to "checked". He is trying to use a button to set all of the checkboxes to "checked".

Comment: Yes the best way its to conserve the BooleanField but apply "$('.checkbox').not('#id_season_0')" and custom the css of this one, no ?

Comment: That will work yes. Personally if you want a button I would use a button rather than using extra css to style a checkbox to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. No matter what select all shouldn't be a field in your models. If you are using a ModelForm you can still add fields after the form is created with `form.fields['season'] = forms.BooleanField()`.

That field won't be saved to the database. But you could also add whatever you want to the html and use it to toggle.

If it was a button I would probably do something like this:

```
$('#selectall').click(function (event) { //on click 
    $(this).toggleClass('checked_all');
    $('.checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('checked_all'));
});
```

Thats a lot less code to do the same thing. You can avoid .each() most of the time with jQuery. If you have multiple objects selected you can change multiple objects in one line.

`$('.checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('checked_all'));`

This says set all the .checkbox elements to the value of $(this).hasClass('checked_all'). (either true or false, and we're toggling it each time with $(this).toggleClass('checked_all')).

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. If I use your method with a button, how can I put this button on the 'season' field ? Because in change_form.html I can only put HTML button on head or bottom of the page but not directly on the fields.

Comment: You can render each field manually or use JavaScript to add it to the page.